# What are fast ways to switch between text styles (font, size, etc) in Microsoft Word or other word processing software?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, speed, text-editors

Many times I need to switch back and forth between 2-3 different styles when writing a document.  I dislike needing to manually click to change the style in the user interface and would like to use a quick key or shortcut.  Does a faster way exist to toggle between fonts styles?

Comment: What do you mean, beyond defining (in the style settings) a shortcut for a style that you have set up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't speak for other applications but for Word, you can apply a short cut to any style.

I use `<alt>-1`, `<alt>-2`, etc. for headings and `<alt>-n` for normal style. Simply modify the style and look for the "Shortcut Key ..." menu under the "Format" button.

Other word processors are likely to have similar capabilities.